# Расположение обьектов в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Немного расширив юайную часть опять столкнулся с проблемой расположения инпута в одну строку со списком.
Прошу помощи, что я делаю не так?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocanma08/3/)

```
div.marks
{
    float: left;   
}

ul.marks {
    padding: 0px 0px 4px 28px;    
}
ul.marks > li .removeMark {   
    display: none;   
}

ul.marks li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 35px;
    background: #79AC26;     
    height: 17px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #C0C0C0;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #C0C0C0;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 3px #C0C0C0;
}

ul.marks li:before {

    content: "";
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/6f07e494a0b5a976e0a2b89b213b53e1/1433263817/1182/915852/tags_box_left.png");
}
ul.marks li:after {

    content: "";
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/1bbf685ae7e0d803cb858a2d7fdd471c/1433428029/939/915852/tags_box_bgr.png");
}
ul.marks li:hover
{    
    background: #669933;     
}
ul.marks > li:hover .removeMark {  
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;   
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index:3;
}

ul.marks li:hover:before {      
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/9cddca7d0ea6b775d349b5576b9a1fd6/1433429186/1200/915852/tags_box_left_hover.png");
}

ul.tags li:hover:after {      
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/776dc03c6da5d048203741168a294336/1433429213/948/915852/tags_box_right_hover.png");
}


<ul class="marks">
  <li>
      Item 1
      <span type="button" class="removeMark">&times;</span>
  </li>
  <li>
      Item 2
      <span type="button" class="removeMark">&times;</span>
  </li>
  <li>
      Item 3
      <span type="button" class="removeMark">&times;</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class = "marks">
    <input></input>
<div>
```

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfdfhf3v/)

```
div.marks
{
   float: left;
   margin: 14px 0 0;
}

ul.marks {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 24px 0 28px;
}
ul.marks > li .removeMark {   
    display: none;
}

ul.marks li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 35px;
    background: #79AC26;     
    height: 17px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #C0C0C0;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px #C0C0C0;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 3px #C0C0C0;
}

ul.marks li:before {
    content: "";
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/6f07e494a0b5a976e0a2b89b213b53e1/1433263817/1182/915852/tags_box_left.png");
}
ul.marks li:after {
    content: "";
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/1bbf685ae7e0d803cb858a2d7fdd471c/1433428029/939/915852/tags_box_bgr.png");
}
ul.marks li:hover
{    
    background: #669933; 
}
ul.marks > li:hover .removeMark {

    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;   
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    display: block;
}

ul.marks li:hover:before {   
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/9cddca7d0ea6b775d349b5576b9a1fd6/1433429186/1200/915852/tags_box_left_hover.png");
}

ul.marks li:hover:after {    
    background: url("http://i.piccy.info/i9/776dc03c6da5d048203741168a294336/1433429213/948/915852/tags_box_right_hover.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/an467kx6/

```css
ul, li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

div {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>           
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
</ul>
<div>Other</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, ответ должен быть похож на этот: http://jsfiddle.net/Haikson/b52f25yx/

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.right-block {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
    <li id="@item.Key">@item.Value</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="right-block">Other</div>
</div>
```